# как изменить порядковый номер дня при вызове функции gettime 'wday

Tags: php, функции

При создании календаря на php , функция getdate начинает день недели с воскресенье (=0) и до субботы.Тогда в таблице у меня календарь смещается на один день .Например: Воскресенье это 1 февраля.

Answer (score 0):

Просто надо было отнять 1 ['wday']-1

Comment: не знаю что вы там делаете, но у функции форматирования даты в пхп `date()` есть два модификатора - `w`, который видимо вы используете, возвращающий воскресенье 0, и `N`, считающий дни 1-7 с пнд по вс.